# The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context [...] for 60 seconds

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting this error on code that used to work.  I have not changed the code.

Here is the full error:

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x3322d98 to COM context 0x3322f08 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.

And here is the code that caused it:

```
var openFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "mdb";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Management Database (manage.mdb)|manage.mdb";

//Stalls indefinitely on the following line, then gives the CLR error
//one minute later.  The dialog never opens.
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    ....
}
```

Yes, I am sure the dialog is not open in the background, and no, I don't have any explicit COM code or unmanaged marshalling or multithreading.

I have no idea why the OpenFileDialog won't open - any ideas?

Comment: I've never seen .Filter used without an asterix.  Try `"Management Database (*.mdb)|*.mdb"` I don't know if that might be confusing something in the framework.

Comment: @Aaron: As I said, it worked just yesterday.  I am only looking for a specific file with that specific name

Comment: It is not an error, it is a *debugger warning*.  Produced by the ContextSwitchDeadlock managed debugging assistant and designed to warn about possible deadlock due to COM marshaling.  OpenFileDialog uses lots of COM.  You'd only ever get it when debugging your app.  Network timeouts are very long, you'd have to wait a while before the true exception is raised.

Comment: How is this Exception not an error? In my case, the exception is raised with the same text on long running operations and never completes the action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out - it automatically brings you to the last location you looked in every time the dialog opens.  If that location is a network location that no longer exists (ex. the other computer is off), it will just hang forever.

My workaround looks like this:

```
string initialDirectory = ...; //Figure out an initial directory from somewhere
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = !Directory.Exists(initialDirectory)
                                       ? Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)
                                       : initialDirectory;
```

Answer (score 25):

One fix for the problem is to go to the Debug -> Exceptions -> Managed Debug Assistants  menu in Visual Studio and uncheck the ContextSwitchDeadlock

From http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/08/16/clr-has-been-unable-to-transition-from-com-context-for-60-seconds/

**Update2. Visual Studio 2019+:**

Debug -> Windows -> Exception settings

Uncheck ContextSwitchDeadlock

Comment: hiding the exception doesn't mean it has gone away!

Comment: This is an **awful** idea.

Comment: Dan, can you please explain, why it's awful?

Comment: Swallowing or hiding any potential issues/exceptions with your code is always an awful idea. What happens down the road when you experience issues within the application and can't see why and this could be the problem area?

Comment: While I would typically agree that swallowing an exception is a bad practice, I just came across this thread trying to solve this problem as well.  This solution worked for my needs.   Don't assume that everyone is building a 2 million lines of code business application -- sometimes in cases such as mine, i'm just writing a small data migration tool, where i don't care that my UI is updating or not.  This solution allowed my program to run unhindered, now i can go back to bed and wait for the morning for it to complete.

Comment: This is not a solution... this is a way to hide the issue which is never a good idea.

Comment: That helped me, Thanks

Comment: the original post is done. Can someone post the code here?

Comment: Debug -> Windows -> Exception settings

Answer (score 14):

So, it's complaining about a COM context even though you're not explicitly using COM because opening a native shell dialog underneath all that lovely c# code, and the shell does use COM.

What this message is telling you is that whatever it's trying to do, it's doing it on the UI thread and not in a nice way, and that seems to be taking a long time.  Obviously whatever is wrong isn't your fault per-se, so you can ignore most of the advice it's giving you.

Things to try:

1. First I would try, as `AaronLS` suggest, simplifying your `openFileDialog` as much as possible.  Try not setting anything; just create a new guy and call `ShowDialog()`.  If that solves the problem, then you've just given it malformed parameters, and we can go talk about the implications of that.  However if it does not work, that means that something is going wrong in shell land.
2. One possible reason this might happen is because you have a shell extension installed that is doing something bad.  The best thing for you to do is `break-in (ctrl+break in Visual Studio` I think, or `debug->break all` on the menu bar) and get the complete stack for us.  We should be able to identify the culprit by seeing who is on the stack when the dialog appears.

Comment: FWIW, the **debug->break all** worked for me. I had a try..catch that failed a lot of times because I had inadvertently caused an exception in the try. Fixed the code and it's back to normal.

Answer (score 9):

I got this problem while working with a large database and it made the UI freeze for a long period. So I put the codes in a `BackgroundWorker` and now the problem is gone. thanks to @i_am_jorf

> What this message is telling you is that whatever it's trying to do,
>   it's doing it on the UI thread and not in a nice way, and that seems
>   to be taking a long time.

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
  bgwConvert.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bgwConvert_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  //My taking-lots-of-time codes
}

private void bgwConvert_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  Cursor = Cursors.Default;
  MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem, and I solved it by changing my .Net framework to the latest one (.Net framework 4.5 in my case; from project properties *Window-> Debug-> .Net Framework*), and changing the CPU type from *x86* to *Any CPU* (in project properties *Window-> Build-> Platform Target*).

Comment: Tried this, and this makes sense if you are on a 64-bit machine but unfortunately this resolved nothing for me. VS 2013 Premium/Windows 10 and I am coding a VSTO Add-In for Excel 2016.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problems moments ago, the solution in my case was simple:
Clean the solution and rebuild it!

I am using Visual Studio 2015.